# How can i rewrite calls on port 8080, 8000 to port 80

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, port

I made a api for usage on an existing software. The software is named iptv-smarters, and what it does is connect to an api and get some informations. The default port for iptv-smarters seems to be 8080 or 8000. I am running my api on a shared hosting, and i want to catch calls to the api on port 8080 or 8000 and redirect them to port 80.

Ive read about rewriting the port with modrewrite, but i get a 404 for all requests including the defaults on port 80. I am also rewriting calls to a subdomain to a script in another subdomain - so i can use the subdomain as client id.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.iptv-manager\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php$).*)$ http://player-api.iptv- 
manager.info/index.php?subdomain=%1&route=$1 [QSA,P]
```

I tried doing this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:80%{REQUEST_URI} 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.iptv-manager\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php$).*)$ http://player-api.iptv- 
manager.info/index.php?subdomain=%1&route=$1 [QSA,P]`
```

But i can't get it to work -

Comment: If it is shared hosting, you probably can't have your website/app listening on 8080 or 8000. You need proper server (VM/Cloud instance, you can get very cheap one or even free), where you can configure your own Apache.

Comment: Thank you - im switching to vps in a short while - so i think i will be able to change it then.